# What does the phrase "there is every chance that" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> And the answer is, "You can always conjure them up! IF they are significant triggers of relaxation in a person then there is a very good chance indeed that you can activate the appropriate system by the techniques we learned in Chapter 1. If someone responds to the touch of a pet, for example, then ***there is every chance that** you can evoke the response via words or pictures, and you should have seen that rocking can be evoked with no expense other than a few minutes of time."

What does the phrase **"there is every chance that"** mean?

What can I use instead of that phrase?

I need some simple examples of using the phrase to understand better the meaning and usage of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is every chance that X will occur

just means that there is a good probability that X will happen.

For example,

> There is every chance you'll find a good job once you finish your degree

means your job prospects are great after graduation.

The phrase does *not* imply certainty, however. It's simply an optimistic phrase, and is often used to cheer someone up who is feeling the odds are stacked against them. And under the definition of *every* we find:

> [**every**](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/every)
>   b. Being all possible: *had every chance of winning, but lost*.

So the phrase suggests success is possible, but certainly not assured.